# Cant generate aar file from project

Tags: android

I am new in creating library from android studio. I have been reading this [***tutorial***](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Convert) in developers website. So to try it out I have created a new project and without doing anything I edited the app level build.gradle file and here is how it looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Now when I am trying to build an apk(which is supposed to build aar file) isn't building anything as I cant see any confirmation message like something when I build an apk nor can't I find anything inside app/build/outputs folder..

Where am I going wrong? Is there anything that I am understanding wrong in the tutorial?

[Here is the project structure - screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzBNY.jpg)

Comment: Can you please post an image of your project structure?

Comment: where is your library package?